# Table needs more than one identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am in no way a SQL expert so I am sure I did something wrong.  I have read a few questions on here about needing a primary key.  The way I created this table I can't find a way to actually have a unique key.  It is a survey type database.  I have a table for the main details like date, triage number, and the person involved.  Another table for the questions results and another for the comments.  I would have made the triage unique but more than one person can be involved so the same triage number would be used more than once.  The people involved can appear more than once as well.  The only truly unique thing is combining the person with the triage.  I thought about an auto key but it would serve no purpose.  Can using two identifiers be an acceptable practice for a survey type table?

Comment: Sounds like you have a many to many relationship.

Comment: Which makes the answer to the final question, Yes.

Comment: Is this acceptable or should I rework the back end.  I read in a few places that sometimes a third table can be used but it feels like it would also not be needed

Comment: Looks acceptable to me.  It even has a name - composite primary key.

Comment: "I thought about an auto key but it would serve no purpose" - it would, to create a unique identifier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part:

"... more than one person can be involved so the same triage number would be used more than once. The people involved can appear more than once as well."

Based on your comments, data in these two fields, for example:

```
 Triage  Person
 ------  ------
    1     PersonA
   1     PersonB
 ...
    7     PersonA
   7     PersonB
```

is fine in that Triage and Person can make a composite key, provided each person recorded in the Person field is uniquely identifiable.  That is, if ea. person value is a name like "John Smith", you may have a problem if there are 2 or more John Smiths answering the survey.  So, your Person value itself has to identify people uniquely.  Assuming the triage nos. are distinguished (i.e., no triage no. represents more than one semantically-relevant triage position), these two fields as the composite key will work for you if and only if at no time does your survey create more than one unique triage-person combination.

The foreign key for each of your other tables ought to be the main table's composite key combination, but if the other two tables can be merged into the main one, consider it to reduce join burdens.  E.g.: if the comments table stores only comments in a single field and nothing more, why not include that field in the main table and get rid of the comments table?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite general and I don't have enough information to give you a definite answer but hopefully my comments below can help.

It is not a problem to use a composite primary key (key consisting of 2 or more columns). It is more often used in linking tables, e.g. in many-to-many relationships.

One thing that you should consider is that if you want to also refer to a table with a composite primary key from other tables, you will have to refer to 2 columns in the foreign key, all the joins, etc. It may be easier to create a separate column for a primary key (e.g. autoincrementing number).